# Zip file being accessed by multiple user - Mem out of exception issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, download

So this is what I have so far

in my view

```
@foreach (var file in item.AssociatedFileList)
{      
    @Html.ActionLink(file.FileName, "GetFile", "Landing", new { path = file.FilePath }, new { target = "_blank" }) <br /><br />
}
```

and my controller

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string path)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        if (extension == ".pdf")
            return File(fs, "application/pdf", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));

        if (extension == ".xlsx" || extension == ".xls")
            return File(fs, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));

        if (extension == ".zip")
            return File(fs, "application/zip", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));                       

       return this.Content("<html><center><span style='font-size: large; font-weight: bold; font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'PT Sans', 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif'; color: #FF0000;'>There is no file to view<span></center></html>");
    }
```

The logic behind displaying the file is ruled by case and sub case
1 case - multiple sub case.
Each subcase is represented by different file types(pdf, excel or zip)

the directory name is case name and file is the directory is subcase with appropriate extension.

to sum it up

C drive has a folder name my application -> it has a account number folders ->  each account has miltiple case folder click on one case say CASE_1 folder -> its has SUBCASE_1.pdf ,  SUBCASE_2.xlsx , SUBCASE_3.zip etc files

**Now each file is displayed on screen independently note: the files have to be displayed independently not zipped at directory(case) level.** when user clicks the action link they can read or download.

```
@Html.ActionLink(file.FileName, "GetFile", "Landing", new { path = file.FilePath }, new { target = "_blank" }) <br /><br />
```

These zip files can be huge

the problem i am facing is when only one user is trying to access the file everything works fine but if more than one user tries to access the file I get

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.    Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value) +93
System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value) +64
System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +330
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.ArteryFilter.Write(Byte[]   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) +106
System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean finalFiltering, IIS7WorkerRequest wr) +9509748
System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput() +104
System.Web.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +49
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

later I checked  the file size of filestream oibject it is 108560843

I am putting everything I can think of in the question. this is my first time working with files and I don't want to miss any detail.

Comment: Disable PageInspector.

Comment: how do i disable page instpector

Comment: Uncheck Enable Browser Link from the dropdown next to Run.

Comment: wow it working now thanks. what does page inspector do to my code that it does not work.

Comment: It tries to buffer the entire file in memory.